# Error system on HXT

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

Is there a way to create an error log with HXT ?
Or do i need to create mine ?
I saw that there is an error system for HXT but there is not so much information available...
My idea was to collect all the error, branches which he didnt parse, and put it on a log file with the corresponding line (branches which he didn't parse) .

**Parsing tree**

## content of:

```
---XTag "owl:Class"
   |   "rdf:about"="http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#Viewer"
   |
   +---XTag "owl:equivalentClass"
      |
      +---XTag "owl:Class"
          |
          +---XTag "owl:oneOf"
              |   "rdf:parseType"="Collection"
              |
              +---XTag "rdf:Description"
              |   |   "rdf:about"="http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#ThroughTheLens"
              |
              +---XTag "rdf:Description"
                  |   "rdf:about"="http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#WindowOnTopOfCamera"
```

If the `rdf:about` isn't there on the `owl:Class`, i must throw an error for example.

Comment: nobody to help me ? :(

Comment: This may help you: https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/advanced-haskell/xml-parsing-with-validation#handling-errors

Comment: But the problem is, i don't think he's recognizing very well, my `getName`! I edited my post, to show you how is recognizing my tree.

Comment: For example, i wanna introduce an error system and if my `owl:Class` doesn't have an `rdf:about`or have something else. it must output an error.

Comment: Finally @Sibi , i did it with a litte different way and of course, with the way as you showed me ! If you wanna the bounty, answer it and i will give you the bounty ! Thank you by the way ! :)

Comment: Glad that you solved it. :) I don't know anything about HXT library, I just thought that the link might be useful for you. :)

Comment: Well, it didn't help me entirely, it has just gived me an hint on how to do it.

Comment: If you want your bounty Sibi, reply as an answer and not a comment like that i will bounty you !

Comment: Thanks, I don't want the bounty. :) Also can you add your answer of how exactly you solved this problem.

Comment: i will do later then. :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you can set an error message handler, which can then be used to write to which ever log you wish.

See http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.4/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlState-ErrorHandling.html

In particular,

- getErrorMessages :: IOStateArrow s b XmlTree
- addToErrorMsgList :: IOStateArrow s XmlTree XmlTree

Comment: But i don't know how to use it ! That's my main problem ! Can you give me an example on how to use it ?

Comment: Can you give me an hint, please ?